# WebAPI route without controller tag

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying out WebAPI and so far I'm impressed, stuggling with routing though. 
I have this route that works:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{query}",
            defaults: new { query = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I would however like to have an 'else' controller (if no controller is found, use this one), my current (non-working) path is:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ElseApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/g/{identifier}",
            defaults: new {
                controller = "Else",
                action = "Generalise",
                identifier = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

With the following method in my ElseController:

```
public string Generalise(string identifier)
        {
            return "gen";
        }
```

What could the problem be? Keep getting a 404 error...

Answer (score 3):

Please remember about adding routes in proper order.

The routing mechanism is using the first route it can match so if the `"api/{controller}/{action}/{query}"` route was defined first, then a call like `api/g/1` will also use this route, not the second on.

Rule of thumb here is to define most specific routes first and most general routes last - you can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742803/routing-in-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc-4/12743757#12743757) for more details.

Comment: I understand that but I do not have a 'g' controller, what I'm trying to achieve is to have a controller that can take a number of paths... my query will not be specifying actions or anything, it will literally only say /api/g/operator, I would then like to receive operator as a string into my method. Is that possible?

Comment: @AdriaanDavel Please read my answer carefully, it is all about routes order. In your case you have defined `"api/{controller}/{action}/{query}"` as the first route so it is the one that framework will use. You don't have 'g' controller so it will fail. But if you define `"api/g/{identifier}"` as the first route, than a call like `/api/g/operator` will be directed to controller `Else` and action `Generalise` while every action which is not starting with '/api/g/...' will be skipped by this route and analyzed by the second, more general one.

Comment: I have moved that route all the way to the top and it is still not finding it... If I add [HttpGet] to my method it gets the method, but it does not pass the identifier...

Comment: @AdriaanDavel I'm sorry but I'm not able to reproduce your issue with RTM version of Web API, can you make a sample project available somewhere so the issue can be further analysed?